# Set layout at bottom of screen and rest fill the parent

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

In my activity there are two `LinearLayout`,`LinearLayout 1` and `LinearLayout 2`. `LinearLayout 2` has to be aligned at the bottom of parent layout and `LinearLayout 1` has to take rest of parent height . I have used `RelativeLayout` and `layout_alignParentBottom` . It is working but `LinearLayout 1` is not taking whole screen , and when i use `fill_parent` for `LinearLayout 1` then it overlaps the `LinearLayout 2` .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4bry.jpg)

Comment: you want the layout 1 to take the remaining space or the complete space and then make layout 2 on top of it?

Comment: No i do not want them to over lap each other . BTW thanks for your interest , i got my question answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#FFF000"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks brother it was helpful as i wanted .